# Could some explain this TSQL code for me?

Tags: sql, t-sql

I got the following stored procedure, but I am new to T-SQL and not quite sure about its syntax. Could some explain a little to me?

Question:

- What does the #tmp syntax stand for?
- Where is the c in c.RootCategoryId defined?

Here's the code:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[GetAllTopCategories]
    @prewin7 bit
AS
SELECT * INTO #tmp FROM dbo.fnGetCategories(@prewin7)

SELECT
    c.RootCategoryId CategoryId,
    c.CategoryName + ' [' + CAST(g.DiagnosticCount AS nvarchar(max)) + ']' CategoryName,
    @prewin7 as PreWin7
FROM (
    SELECT
        c.RootCategoryId CategoryId,
        SUM(c.DiagnosticCount) DiagnosticCount
    FROM #tmp c
    GROUP BY c.RootCategoryId
) g
INNER JOIN #tmp c ON c.CategoryId = g.CategoryId
ORDER BY c.CategoryName

DROP TABLE #tmp
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `#tmp` is a local temporary table, e.g. it is only ever visible to the connection that created it, and once that connection is gone, so is the temporary table. So that `DROP TABLE #tmp` at the end is really not necessary - the table would be dropped automatically by SQL Server.

This temporary table was created here:

```
SELECT * INTO #tmp FROM dbo.fnGetCategories(@prewin7)
```

so it will contain any of the rows that the result set from the `dbo.fnGetCategories` stored function will return.

```
SELECT
    c.RootCategoryId CategoryId,
    SUM(c.DiagnosticCount) DiagnosticCount
FROM #tmp c
```

Here, data is selected from that temporary table, which has a table alias of `c` - so therefore, that `c.RootCategoryId` must be a column of that temporary table, and thus it must be one of the rows that is returned from the stored function called above.

Comment: hmm... the drop table is not that redundant. If this code is executed by a server that keeps a connection open the temp tables can build up.

Comment: @gjvdkamp - local temp tables are actually dropped when a stored proc exits, if they're created within a stored proc, rather than when the connection is closed, so it's still redundant.

Answer (score 0):

Do you really need a temp table?

```
   ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[GetAllTopCategories]
        @prewin7 bit
    AS

    /*SELECT * INTO #tmp FROM dbo.fnGetCategories(@prewin7)*/

    SELECT
        c.RootCategoryId CategoryId,
        c.CategoryName + ' [' + CAST(g.DiagnosticCount AS nvarchar(max)) + ']' CategoryName,
        @prewin7 as PreWin7
    FROM (
        SELECT
            c.RootCategoryId CategoryId,
            SUM(c.DiagnosticCount) DiagnosticCount
        FROM (select * FROM dbo.fnGetCategories(@prewin7)) c
        GROUP BY c.RootCategoryId
    ) g
    INNER JOIN (select * FROM dbo.fnGetCategories(@prewin7)) c ON c.CategoryId = g.CategoryId
    ORDER BY c.CategoryName
```

Comment: If you post code or XML, **please** highlight those lines in the text editor and click on the "code" button (101 010) on the editor toolbar to nicely format and syntax highlight it!

Comment: No problem - next time you know :-)